# kafka is not electiong new leader after 2 nodes are down

Tags: apache-kafka, replication, partitioning, kafka-topic

we test scalein in enviorment with 3 kafka nodes
each one has a broker and zookeeper service on in
the replica.factor=2
after the service went down on 2 nodes
the leader of the partition stayed the old one and didnt movve to the only node that is up

and a a error message is sent

Error: partition 0 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets
Error: partition 2 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets
Error: partition 3 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets

why this could happen?

[here you can see how the leaders stayed even though there is replica set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoCo1.png)

Comment: As far as I understand Kafka can not find a new leader since the replica is 2, but there is only one node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [kafka configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)

> The replication factor for the offsets topic (set higher to ensure availability). Internal topic creation will fail until the cluster size meets this replication factor requirement.

I guess that kafka cluster can not serve or do anything with a topic that has replica factor that is bigger than it's cluster size

Comment: but if I want to preform scale in its impossible with replica factor=2?

Comment: What do you mean by scale -> more parallelize / more data / more replication ? Replication factor is just a configuration for how many copies of your data you want

Comment: ok and if 2 nodes are down if I will truncate the data from topic and restart zookeeper and kafka service it sould worked?